# adb shell start can't start activity because of timeout?

Tags: android

I am trying to start an app on an emulator instance, but keep getting a timeout error. Example:

```
$ adb shell am start -S -W org.me/org.me.TestActivity
```

result:

```
Stopping: org.me
Starting: Intent { ... }
Status: timeout
Activity: org.me/org.me.TestActivity
WaitTime: 14533
Complete
```

I'm not sure where the `timeout` threshold comes from, the docs don't mention it - anyone know how to increase it?

I have a generic Hello World app which I can launch the same way without any issue, just to test that my setup is otherwise correct.

I have seen some other people run into this, but they are able to modify some "timeout" setting through their IDE (eclipse) for this - but I am running without any IDE, so I'm not sure what the equivalent is.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to start the emulator itself (without your app)?

Comment: Yes the emulator is running, and I can start a simple Hello World app using the same command.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am facing te same issue, and this thread seems to be only relevant hit on google..